# Order Dates between a stop and start date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Visitid LocationName    TransferRequestDtm        TransEndDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
296459  Waiting         2016-06-04 22:53:46.000   2016-06-04 23:01:30.650
296459  ED-22           2016-06-04 23:01:30.650   2016-06-05 01:16:00.000
296459  CCS-CC28-A      2016-06-05 01:16:00.000   2016-06-14 06:26:35.000
296459  4N-N450-A       2016-06-14 06:26:35.000   2016-06-14 06:33:41.530
296459  4N-N450-A       2016-06-14 06:33:41.530   2016-06-16 11:51:44.443
```

I have a table in which order start and stop dates that I need to determine if they fall between the `TransferRequestDtm` and the `TransEndDate`.

How do I do this in SQL? I have read elsewhere that I can use

```
WHERE 
    (OrderStart '2016-06-01', OrderStop '2016-06-16')
```

overlaps (TransferRequestDtm, TransEndDate) but that doesn't work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select records between two dates in two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479080/select-records-between-two-dates-in-two-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I would just write the logic as:

```
where OrderStart <= TransEndDate and OrderStop >= TransferRequestDtm
```

However, I have no idea what the date constant strings are doing in the query.

Note  this implements partial overlap, which seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: I have a problem when the Visitid has more then one row. 
296459 OrderStart 2016-06-10  OrderStop 2016-06-13 
296459 OrderStart 2016-06-06  OrderStop 2016-06-16

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE TransferRequestDtm >= '2013-01-03' 
  AND TransEndDate <= '2013-01-09'
```

Or you can also try

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE TransferRequestDtm BETWEEN TransferRequestDtm AND TransEndDate;
```

If you want to compare `TransferReuestDtm` and `TransEndDate` should be between some specific date then you can use

```
DECLARE @FrmDt DATETIME, @ToDt DATETIME
SELECT @FrmDt='2016-01-03', @ToDt='2016-01-09'

SELECT * 
FROM TableName
WHERE (@FrmDt BETWEEN TransferReuestDtm AND TransEndDate) OR 
    (@ToDt BETWEEN TransferReuestDtm AND TransEndDate)
```